# Aggregating Metrics to Form a New Metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm looking for a source or hints which could help me solve the following problem:

Let $S$ be a set and let $d_i : S \times S \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a family of metrics for $i \in \{1, \ldots n\}$. Let $f : [0,1]^n \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a function. What conditions must $f$ fulfil, such that the following function is also a metric?
$$d: S \times S \rightarrow [0,1], \quad d(s,t) = f(d_1(s,t), \ldots, d_n(s,t))$$

To be a metric $d$ must fulfil the following properties for all $s,t,u \in S$:

1. $d(s,t) = d(t,s)$ (symmetry)
2. $d(s,t) = 0$ if and only if $s = t$ (definiteness)
3. $d(s,u) \leq d(s,t) + d(t,u)$ (triangle inequality)

Symmetry follows directly from the definition of the $d_i$. Definiteness is fairly easy to achieve (e.g. with $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0$ if and only if $x_i = 0$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$). The biggest challenge here is the triangle inequality. I only have vague ideas (e.g. continuity or monotonicity of $f$) for that condition. Any suggestions?

EDIT: As mentioned by Aram, the problem becomes slightly simpler if all restrictions to $[0,1]$ are replaced with $[0, \infty]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you have

1. $f$ inyective
2. $f(0) = 0$
3. $f$ is monotone increasing
4. $f$ continuous

But this conditions aren't sufficient, because you might have (on $[0,1]$ ), $f(x) = x^2$, $f(x) \leq f(x+y)$ but you can test that $f(x+y) \not\leq f(x)+f(y)$ for some values.

So far I've found this sufficient conditions:

$1)$

1. $f$ monotone increasing
2. $f$ is linear
3. $f(1) = 1$.

Or

$2)$

1. $f$ is subadditive (triangle inequality).
2. $f$ is monotone increasing.
3. $f(1) = 1$.
4. $f(0) = 0$.
5. $f$ is inyective.

Checking its a distance for $1)$. Because it doesnt distinguish between $d(x,y)$ and $d(y,x)$ you see is symmetric (In fact you have already noted this). Now $$f(0) = f(0 + 0) = f(0) + f(0)$$ That means $f(0) = 0$. Now triangly inequality follows because $$f(d(x,y)) \leq f(d(x,z) + d(z,y)) = f(d(x,z)) + f(d(z,y))$$

If the distance you were trying to construct was a standard distance ($d: M \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})$ you could drop $3$ from both.

Comment: What do you mean for example by $f(1) = 1$? $f$ is a function of $n$ variables.

Comment: @user87690 I'm thinking the case where $n= 1$. Can you take it to $n$ variables?

Comment: If you modify point 4. as follows $f(a) = 0 \Leftrightarrow a = 0$ then injectivity is not explicitly required. That would leave $f$ subadditive and monotone, with the modified point 4.